# Duplicate values but with different strings

Tags: powershell

Hello if i have 2 text files like this

**file1**

```
jack : 10
donald : 50
mark : 20
florence : 15
ariel : 50
arnold : 50
```

**file2**

```
jack
country : ohaio

donald
country : italy

mark
country : france

florence
country : china

ariel
country :america

arnold
country: japan
```

how can i to get country names of people older than 20 looping through ages in file1 to get names of people first then after i get names loop through them in file2 to get countries.// don't know how to deal with duplicate ages,this is just sample files there is a lot more values than that.

so output should be something like this:

```
ages

10
20
50
15
50
50

values over 20

50
50
50

names

donald
ariel
arnold


countries

italy
america
japan
```

Comment: Please use code-fences (`\`\`\``) to show _exactly_ what your text file contents looks like

Comment: [1] is there an actual blank line between each record in `File2`? [2] are `File1` and `File2` _always in the exact same sequence_?

Comment: [3] is the `:` after `country` supposed to always have a space on each side?

Comment: [4] are the two input files always the same number of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code presumes the entries in the two files are in the EXACT same sequence ... and they have EXACTLY the same number of entries. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- sets the name & location of the input files
- creates the files to work with
  comment out or remove this region when ready to work with real data.
- reads in the 1st file as an array of single lines
- reads in the 2nd file as an array of 3-line chunks
- iterates thru the two collections in parallel using the index number of the 1st collection
  the `.GetUpperBound(0)` gets the upper limit of the zero axis of the collection.
- builds a `PSCustomObject` of the desired items
  it uses the `$Index` to decide what to work on.
  the `[1]` after the Country file index grabs the 2nd line of the 3-line chunk.
- sends the PSCO out to the `$Results` collection
- displays it on screen
- filters the collection for the items where the `.Age` property is over 20

the code ...

```
$File_1_Name = "$env:TEMP\3N16M4_File1.txt"
$File_2_Name = "$env:TEMP\3N16M4_File2.txt"

#region >>> create files to work with
$NameAge = @'
jack : 10
donald : 50
mark : 20
florence : 15
ariel : 50
arnold : 50
'@ | Set-Content -LiteralPath $File_1_Name -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'

$NameCountry = @'
jack
country : ohaio

donald
country : italy

mark
country : france

florence
country : china

ariel
country :america

arnold
country: japan
'@  | Set-Content -LiteralPath $File_2_Name -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
#endregion >>> create files to work with

$NameAge = Get-Content -LiteralPath $File_1_Name
# the "-ReadCount" parameter grabs lines in groups
$NameCountry = Get-Content -LiteralPath $File_2_Name -ReadCount 3

# this code presumes the two files are in the EXACT same sequence
#   and that they have EXACTLY the same number of entries
$Results = foreach ($Index in 0..$NameAge.GetUpperBound(0))
    {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $NameAge[$Index].Split(':')[0].Trim()
        Age = $NameAge[$Index].Split(':')[-1].Trim()
        Country = ($NameCountry[$Index][1] -replace '(?ms).+:', '').Trim()
        }
    }

# show whole collection on screen
$Results
'=' * 30
# show the filtered results
$Results.Where({$_.Age -gt 20})
```

on screen display - the whole collection is above the line, the filtered items are below it ...

```
Name     Age Country
----     --- -------
jack     10  ohaio  
donald   50  italy  
mark     20  france 
florence 15  china  
ariel    50  america
arnold   50  japan  
==============================
donald   50  italy  
ariel    50  america
arnold   50  japan
```

Comment: ok that works but what if the file1 and file2 have another lines and data than the ones i mentioned, and those lines are not needed we just need ones that we got with above code , same format but with more people and more ages and more lines that are not related to that.

Comment: @3N16M4 - you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// as i implied, your sanitized sample data MUST match your actual data in order for anyone to do any realistic work. without seeing a _realistic_ data set, all anyone can do is make wild guesses.